# <cache> Failed to run query

Tags: ignite

I'm using Ignite.NET 2.7.6. There is a configuration from one server and about 40 clients. Sometimes I see the following in the server's log:

> Failed to run query [qry=GridCacheQueryInfo [loc=false, trans=null, rdc=null, qry=GridCacheQueryAdapter [type=SCAN, clsName=null, clause=null, filter=o.a.i.i.processors.platform.cache.PlatformCacheEntryFilterImpl@35885169, transform=null, part=null, incMeta=false, metrics=null, pageSize=1024, timeout=0, incBackups=false, forceLocal=false, dedup=false, prj=null, keepBinary=true, subjId=bdf0d106-9634-4562-8032-3520f5b66abf, taskHash=0, mvccSnapshot=null], locFut=null, sndId=bdf0d106-9634-4562-8032-3520f5b66abf, reqId=4502, incMeta=false, all=false], node=15c7b576-6f4b-4eae-86a1-3b98e37b69e5]

The cause of this problem is described nextly:

> class org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: (Null reference in russian) Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта.
>
> at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.query.GridCacheQueryManager$InternalScanFilter.apply(GridCacheQueryManager.java:3142)
>
> at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.query.GridCacheQueryManager$ScanQueryIterator.advance(GridCacheQueryManager.java:3073)
>
> at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.query.GridCacheQueryManager$ScanQueryIterator.onHasNext(GridCacheQueryManager.java:2965)

Caused by:

> Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: (Null reference in russian) Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта.
>
> at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.platform.callback.PlatformCallbackUtils.inLongOutLong(Native Method)
>
> at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.platform.callback.PlatformCallbackGateway.cacheEntryFilterApply(PlatformCallbackGateway.java:143)
>
> at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.platform.cache.PlatformCacheEntryFilterImpl.apply(PlatformCacheEntryFilterImpl.java:70)
>
> at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.query.GridCacheQueryManager$InternalScanFilter.apply(GridCacheQueryManager.java:3139)

Full log can be found here: https://yadi.sk/d/LF03Vz5vz4tRcw

Comment: This looks like a NRE in your C# implementation of entryFilter. Can you wrap all its content in try/log?

Comment: It looks you're right. I'll inspect the issue and post the results.

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks like the bug is inside the NET wrapper for Ignite: I wrapped entire ICacheEntryFilter's Invoke in try/catch with logging, but the exception is still occurs

Comment: Please try catching this exact exception to trace it to any specific portion of Ignite code.

Comment: I found where it crashes: it's NET Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Unmanaged.UnmanagedCallbacks.CacheEntryFilterApply var t == null, so t.Invoke(stream) throws NullPointerException

Comment: Started https://stackoverflow.com/q/58632391/5821570

Comment: The solution was found, more details here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58632391/5821570